# can i create html elements like <html>,<head><body> by using CreateElement() i javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

can i create html elements like `<html>,<head><body>` by using CreateElement() ?

for example
`let ele= document.CreateElement('html')` or 'body' or 'head'

Comment: Did you try it in the console? See what it does?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did you get errors in the console?

Comment: OK I did it for you : `let ele=document.createElement('html'); document.append(ele);` --> `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Document': Only one element on document allowed.` So you have your answer :)

Comment: what is the meaning of only one element on document allowed?

Comment: You are trying to create another `<html>` tag. The response is : `Error, only one allowed`. What do you think this means?

Answer (score 1):

NO!
Its not possible because you cant add a html to a existing html document.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create  tag inside  tag to an existing html document. You can't do that. *Don't use qualified names (like "html:a") with this method. When called on an HTML document, createElement() converts tagName to lower case before creating the element.*